# C# marshaling C struct

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke, dllimport

I've this C-C# code that works:

.h

```
typedef struct {

  float a;
  float b;

} MyStruct;

extern MyStruct mystruct;

__declspec(dllexport) void  GetMyStruct (MyStruct* s);
__declspec(dllexport) void  SetMyStruct (MyStruct* s);
```

.c

```
    MyStruct mystruct;

    void GetMyStruct (MyStruct* s)
    {

        *s = AeroLink_IOPkt;
    }

    void SetMyStruct (MyStruct* s)
    {

        AeroLink_IOPkt = *s; 
    }

void test()
{
   // some code that update element in struct
   // mystruct.a = 0.4;
   // mystruct.a = 0.1;
}
```

.cs

```
public struct MyStruct
{

  public float a;
  public float b;

} 


[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "GetMyStruct")]
protected static extern void GetMyStruct(ref MyStruct s);

[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "SetMyStruct")]
protected static extern void SetMyStruct(ref MyStruct s);
```

This way, every time I need to set data from C# to C, I must call `void SetMyStruct` and vice-versa if I want to get data from C (updated from void test) to C# I must call  `GetMyStruct`. I must do this 50 times per seconds.

Is there a way to avoid calling `SetMyStruct` and `GetMyStruct` every time? I would like to use `SetMyStruct` one time and then have all changes be reflected, from and to. I do not know if this is possible.

Comment: Try changing from `struct` to `class` and remove the various `ref` keywords

Comment: It is technically possible for a very simple struct like this.  You can expose a function that returns MyStruct* to return a pointer to c.  And use `unsafe` code in your C# program to directly access its a and b members.  But you did make one mistake, you did not check if you *needed* to optimize this code.  Calling it only 60 times per second, you most definitely don't.  This is very fast code, you can call it hundreds of millions of times per second.

Comment: @Olaf just out of curiosity: what is the reason why you removed the `c` tag from this question?

Comment: @PJvG: Because it does not ask about C, but C#. If the C tag was allowed for any question calling a C function, it would have to be added to every question. That's not how it is meant to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `unsafe` and pointers.

You need to compile your C# program with "Unsafe" enabled.

EDIT: A better way:

Add a following function to the library:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void  GetMyStructRef (MyStruct** s);
void GetMyStructRef(MyStruct** s)
{
    *s = &mystruct;
}
```

In C#:

```
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "GetMyStructRef")]
protected static extern void GetMyStructRef(ref MyStruct* s);

MyStruct* data;
GetMyStructRef(ref data);
Console.WriteLine($"{data->a} {data->b}");
```

Old answer:

```
unsafe class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "GetMyStruct")]
    protected static extern void GetMyStruct(MyStruct* s);

    [DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "SetMyStruct")]
    protected static extern void SetMyStruct(MyStruct* s);

    GCHandle handle;
    MyStruct* structRef;

    public void MyClass()
    {
        //we need to get a pinned reference to your struct
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(new MyStruct(), GCHandleType.Pinned);
        structRef = (MyStruct*)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();

        SetMyStruct(structRef);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //We need to free the handle to release memory
        //GC will not collect it without this
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to have a class with unmanaged resources, you need to make it a bit more sophisticated than that. [Lostechies: IDisposable, Done Right](https://lostechies.com/chrispatterson/2012/11/29/idisposable-done-right/)